# how to achieve screencast similar to Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I am working on implementing application which has functionalities similar to Android Auto App.

Basically, what I understand from Android Auto App - it creates UI on Mobile Phone and transfers the UI using USB to Android Carkit to display. Please correct me If my understanding is wrong.

Can someone please help me to understand how does Android Auto casts its screen content to Carkit? How can I implement the similar functionality in my Application?

Comment: You can take a snapshot of the WebView but I don't believe you can capture a "video". What would this "video" be capturing? Is it just streaming content from the device? It doesn't make sense. A possibility would be to capture a screenshot every X seconds and compile the images into a video, which is an advanced procedure for a newbie.

Comment: Matt, I would like to build an application similar to Android Auto which projects its screen to Carkit. Do you have any idea how Android Auto is implemented?

Comment: Android Auto is not a WebView. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yes, Android Auto is not a WebView. but I want to implement app which creates WebView and project or Stream screen contents to Carkit similar to what Android Auto does currently (like it displays UI for maps, messages and Audio Applicaitons).

Comment: Matt K, Can you please suggest if you have pointers for this Issue?

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish this, it is above my Android knowledge. Maybe rephrase your question or add more details or tags to see if anyone else can help you. Maybe use the terms "screencast" or "stream" to get more views.

Comment: Take a look at the MediaRouter class - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html

Answer (score 2):

Android auto provides texture views for rendering contents from different processes associated with it. These renderings are finally composited based on the layout framework defined within Android Auto. The final contents are streamed to the head unit by a Service (using Android Auto Protocol).
Head Unit will contain Android Auto Receiver Library which takes care of getting these data and doing the rest of the jobs. Basically the architecture is complex.

Not all these aspects are open. Have to dig in ,reverse engineer, read logs and figure out more details.